# Pandoc died with exitcode "43" during conversion: b"Error producing PDF

Tags: markdown, pdf-generation, pandoc

I'm getting an error while PDF output stage with Apostrophe which markdown editor!

```markdown
An error happened while trying to export:
Pandoc died with exitcode "43" during conversion: b"Error producing PDF. 
! LaTeX Error: File default.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed, 
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name: ! 
Emergency stop. <read >

1.23 \usepackage
Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fix some illegitimate, redundant **YAML header** options or lineup.

```
---
   geometry: margins=3cm
   fontfamily: default
   fontsize:12pt
...
```

Fix it

```
---
   geometry: margin=3cm
   fontsize:12pt
...
```